# CTRL+C not working in hidden <div>

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, copy-paste

I wanted to have a feature wherein the user can just copy the contents of a particular  by just clicking a single button and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

The following works if I don't put `style="display: none"` to my divToCopy. However, when I place the style, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> will no longer work.

```js
var Clipboard = function() {

  var clipboard = {};

  clipboard.cssStyle = "";
  clipboard.cssClass = "";
  clipboard.targetId = "";

  clipboard.highlight = function(targetId) {
    // backup the styling of the target div
    clipboard.cssStyle = $("#" + targetId).attr('style');
    clipboard.cssClass = $("#" + targetId).attr('class');

    // create a ranged selection
    window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
    if (window.getSelection) {
      console.log("has selection");
      var node = document.getElementById("divToCopy");
      var range = document.createRange();
      console.log(range);
      range.selectNodeContents(node);
      window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
      window.getSelection().addRange(range);
    }

    // highlight
    $("#" + targetId).css("background-color", "yellow");
  };

  clipboard.copyWithStyle = function(targetId) {
    var toCopy = $('#' + targetId).html();
    $('#divToCopy').html(toCopy);

    clipboard.targetId = targetId;
    clipboard.highlight(targetId);
  };

  clipboard.copyNoStyle = function(targetId) {
    var toCopy = $('#' + targetId).html();
    $('#divToCopy').html(toCopy);

    $('#divToCopy *').removeAttr('style');
    $('#divToCopy *').removeAttr('class');

    clipboard.targetId = targetId;
    clipboard.highlight(targetId);
  };

  $("#divToCopy").bind('copy', function() {
    $("#" + clipboard.targetId).attr('style', clipboard.cssStyle);
    $("#" + clipboard.targetId).attr('class', clipboard.cssClass);
  });

  return clipboard;
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  var c = Clipboard();
  $("#copy-with-style").click(function(event) {
    c.copyWithStyle("content");
  });

  $("#copy-no-style").click(function(event) {
    c.copyNoStyle("content");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="my-body" align="center">
  <br/>
  <div id="content" style="text-align:left; margin:0 auto; border: 1px solid black; width: 300px; padding: 5px;">
    <div style="color:red">RED by Taylor Swift</div>
    <ul>
      <li>One</li>
      <li style="font-weight:bold;">Two</li>
      <li>3</li>
      <li>Four</li>
      <li>~!@#$%^&*()______+{}[]:";'
        <>?,./"</li>
    </ul>
    <table style="border:1px solid green;">
      <tr>
        <td colspan=2>Merged</td>
        <td style="color:blue;">Blue</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Red</td>
        <td>Green</td>
        <td>Violet</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <br/>
  <input type="button" value="Copy With Style" id="copy-with-style" />
  <input type="button" value="Copy Without Style" id="copy-no-style" />

  <div id="divToCopy" style="display: none" contenteditable="true"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: are you asking about clipboard copy ?

Comment: `display:none` takes it out of the dom, so it wont be there to copy. Why have ctlr+c copy hidden content?

Comment: Using jsfiddle is fine as long as you add the relevant part of the code. Also keep in mind that you can use snipplets.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `display:none;` Use `visibility:hidden` This might work for you.

Answer (score 1):

don't use:

```
display: none;
visibility: hidden;
```

use:

```
width: 1px;
height: 1px;
overflow: hidden;
```

Comment: Can you add some commentary as to why your solution works?